# \n when splitting in a file python

Tags: python, split

I have a few lines in my file and I'm going through line by line splitting them into what I want. However the last element has \n and I don't want it there. Any advice?

File:

```
link1_Elvis Presley_Hound Dog 
link2_Chubby Checker_The Twist 
link3_Chuck Berry_Johnny B Goode
```

output after splitting:

```
['link1', 'Elvis Presley', 'Hound Dog \n']
['link2', 'Chubby Checker', 'The Twist \n']
['link3', 'Chuck Berry', 'Johnny B Goode']
```

Comment: `str.strip("\n")`

Comment: You could strip them.Can you share the few lines that produce that out come? Because I’m on of the step, you could do x = [i.strip('\n')for i in Iterates]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can strip away the new line characters as follows:

```
line = line.rstrip('\n')
```